# Why does updating my MTGO always comes up with protocol errors?

Tags: technical-issues, magic-the-gathering-online

I frequently experience "protocol errors" while updating Magic: The Gathering Online.  Every time, the error is a different number. It's as if the server gets interrupted during updates or the location on the server is invalid, or something like that.

Question: Is there a way to download the update files manually, i.e. off a zipped file or something?

EDIT-ADD-ON: (Eg of one of the numerous protocol errors, each time a different file~)
[image: Image of protocol error]

Comment: I cannot help with your issue, but I think this should be retagged with a MTG:O tag.

Comment: What is one of the messages that comes after "protocol error"? Try delete the `NewFilelist.txt` file located in the MtGO directory and trying again.

Comment: Thanks guys, do note that even after I deleted NewFilelist.txt and reupdates, I face the same error message again. *stumped*

Answer (score 2):

There is a FAQ for the most common MTG-Online errors here: http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75846/27085537/MTGO_Technical_Issues_FAQ!_*Start_Here

For your protocol error, as Krazer stated, the recommended fix (See also section 1-7 in the link above) is listed as such:

```
Delete the NewFilelist.txt file located in the MtGO directory, then start.
```